# Slow network PC opening in network places

Tags: networking, performance

In *[My Network Places](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Network_Places)* when I try to open a computer, it opens very slowly, but other PCs open quickly. What can be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Two methods of accessing network locations and avoiding performance issues:

1. Create a drive map and use this to browse the network files
2. Create a shortcut to explorer.exe and pass the UNC name of the resource:

`explorer /e, \\Server\FileShare`

Answer (score 0):

Some great tips: http://ss64.com/nt/slow_browsing.html

Mapped drives are great if you use them regularly, but if you actually have to browse for it, the fastest way, is to install a WINS server.. overkill for a home network, but essential for a large corp.

The best way to troubleshoot it, is with wireshark(1), it will tell you everything that your box does over the net while you are waiting.. which can get very enlightening.

For further help, you might need to provide some more information:

1. Are you on a work computer? (what infrastructure is supporting you? DNS/DHCP/WINS etc)
2. How many machines are on your LAN?
3. Which Operating System are you using? (win9x/me/nt/2k/xp/V/7/2k3/2k8)
4. Is your computer doing anything else at the time? (overloaded box = slow)
5. Where is the "other computer" in relation to you? (does it traverse a VPN or sat-link?)

(1) Network Protocol Analyser: www.wireshark.org

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a domain it should be fast to use the computers name in a UNC path such as:

`\\COMPUTER01\shareName`

If you aren't on a domain and in a workgroup instead, it generally takes longer to open the remote machines shares. Instead try using the IP address of the machine instead of its name.

`\\192.168.0.1\shareName`

Either way, once that initial connection is made, it is cached for so long in your system. As mentioned in earlier answers, mapping a network drive may make it faster as well.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a very small network (Not many machines connecting to the shared computer) you can't edit each clients host file located in %System%\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\ .

Add the IP address and the name of the computer (found in system properties / Computer name Tab). The format of the file looks like this http://www.ezlan.net/host.html

Now the clients connecting to the share will no exatly where to go to get to the share. One caveat though....the computer sharing the the files must be statically addressed (No DHCP)!